# On the spectrum of Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, hermitian

I'm working on the adjacency matrix of some graphs and need some facts about Hermitian matrices which have exactly two distinct eigenvalues. Can anybody help me introduce source about spectrum of Hermitian matrices or more generally about these matrices?

Bests.

Comment: What do you actually want to know about such matrices? Any Hermitian matrix is diagonalizable by the spectral theorem, as found in many linear algebra textbooks, and then you can read off the eigenvalues from the diagonal entries

Comment: Aren't the adjacency matrices usually symmetric (as opposed to just Hermitian)?

Answer (score 2):

It is a well known fact that a graph whose adjacency matrix has two distinct eigenvalues is the complet graph, see

*Brouwer, Andries E.; Haemers, Willem H.*, [**Spectra of graphs**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4614-1939-6), Universitext. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 978-1-4614-1938-9/hbk; 978-1-4614-1939-6/ebook). xiii, 250 p. (2012). [ZBL1231.05001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1231.05001).